# JAI: How do I extract a single page input stream from a multipaged TIFF image container?

Tags: java, tiff, jai

I have a component that converts PDF documents to images, *one image per page*. Since the component uses converters producing in-memory images, it hits the JVM heap heavily and takes some time to finish conversions.

I'm trying to improve the overall performance of the conversion process, and found a native library with a JNI binding to convert PDFs to TIFFs. That library can convert PDFs to single TIFF files only (requires intermediate file system storage; does not even consume conversion streams), therefore result TIFF files have converted pages embedded, and not per-page images on the file system. Having a native library improves the overall conversion drastically and the performance gets really faster, but there is a real bottleneck: since I have to make a source-page to destination-page conversion, now I must extract every page from the result file and write all of them elsewhere. A simple and naive approach with `RenderedImage`s:

```java
final SeekableStream seekableStream = new FileSeekableStream(tempFile);
final ImageDecoder imageDecoder = createImageDecoder("tiff", seekableStream, null);
...
//                                               V--- heap is wasted here
final RenderedImage renderedImage = imageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(pageNumber);
// ... do the rest stuff ...
```

Actually speaking, I would really like just to extract a concrete page input stream from the TIFF container file (`tempFile`) and just redirect it to elsewhere without having it to be stored as an in-memory image. I would imagine an approach similar to containers processing where I need to seek for a specific entry to extract data from it (say, something like ZIP files processing, etc). But I couldn't find anything like that in `ImageDecoder`, or I'm probably wrong with my expectations and just missing something important here...

Is it possible to extract TIFF container page input streams using JAI API or probably third-party alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong, but don't think JAI has support for splitting TIFFs without decoding the files to in-memory images. And, sorry for promoting my own library, but I think it does exactly what you need (the main part of the solution used to split TIFFs is contributed by a third party).

By using the [`TIFFUtilities`](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/contrib/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/contrib/tiff/TIFFUtilities.java) class from `com.twelvemonkeys.contrib.tiff`, you should be able to split your multi-page TIFF to multiple single-page TIFFs like this:

```
TIFFUtilities.split(tempFile, new File("output"));
```

No decoding of the images are done, only splitting each IFD into a separate file, and writing the streams with corrected offsets and byte counts.

Files will be named `output/0001.tif`, `output/0002.tif` etc. If you need more control over the output name or have other requirements, you can easily modify the code. The code comes with a BSD-style license.

Comment: _No decoding of the images are done_ -- this is the point that I didn't 100% know when I posted the question (I just assumed it might look like a ZIP container). As far as I understand how TIFF is implemented, it's just a container, and it's might be very easy to rip off each image by page number from the container, right? So, if I'm getting it right, `TIFFUtilities.split` makes zero-overhead in sense that it does not do any image encoding/decoding, therefore it emits the TIFF images set as-is as in the form they, images, were originally stored in the container?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Yes, TIFF is in some respects a container format. However, because image data and tags and tag data (the IFD) can all be stored interleaved, it's slightly harder than just finding a single offset and write from there. The metadata for each IFD will change, and have to be rewritten for each new file. But the image data itself will be copied unchanged, so yes, the overhead should be negligible.

Comment: That's awesome because your library saves a lot and does what no other libs known to me do, thanks! Just one question: does your library support extracting images by page number and redirecting single-paged images to output streams rather than generating single-page image files?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv No, not right out of the box. But I think you should be able to rework the `split` method to do just that with some small changes.

Comment: I've just checked the `split` method implementation and it looks extremely simple, so it can be easily implemented to meet what I want. Thank you!

Comment: @i tried to use the class in the link above but there are lots of compilation errors, it's better to add this class in the published jar to be easy to use.

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh It’s already published as part of the contrib JAR. And it complies just fine locally and on the CI servers..  So I don’t think I follow.

Comment: @haraldK when i downloaded the latest jars from maven i couldn't find the utils class mentioned above : `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-jpeg</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version> <!-- Alternatively, build your own version -->
        </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
         <artifactId>imageio-tiff</artifactId>
         <version>3.3.2</version> <!-- Alternatively, build your own version -->
     </dependency>`