# Processing large TIFF files and memory allocation

Tags: java, memory, tiff, javax.imageio

I've been working on an application that takes a TIFF file that may be very large and split it into multiple, smaller files. In order to do so it needs to iterate through all pages (`BufferedImage` objects) and perform some actions to establish whether new file should be started here or this particual page is a part of already created file.

Obviously I cannot load the whole file into memory - that's why I only read a single page of it using `ImageIO`. I created a util class with methods:

```
public static BufferedImage getSinglePageFromTiffFile(File file, int pageIndex) throws IOException {
    ImageInputStream is = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
    ImageReader reader;
    try {
        reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(is).next();
        reader.setInput(is);
        return reader.read(pageIndex);
    } finally {
        if(is != null) is.close();
    }
}

public static int getNumPages(File file) throws IOException {
    ImageInputStream is = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
    ImageReader reader;
    try {
        reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(is).next();
        reader.setInput(is);
        return reader.getNumImages(true);
    } finally {
        if(is != null) is.close();
    }
}
```

To write pages into file I use `ImageWriter` class like this:

```
int pagesQty = ImageUtils.getNumPages(documentToSplit);
    int currentPageIndex = 0;

    final ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(resultsExtension).next();
    final ImageWriteParam writeParams = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    writeParams.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_COPY_FROM_METADATA);

    BufferedImage page = ImageUtils.getSinglePageFromTiffFile(file, currentPageIndex);

    while(currentPageIndex < pagesQty) {
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        ImageOutputStream imgOutStream = null;

        final File newDocFile = new File(pathName);

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(newDocFile);
            imgOutStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outStream);

            writer.setOutput(imgOutStream);
            writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);

            writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(page, null, null), writeParams);
            currentPageIndex++;

            while(currentPageIndex < pagesQty) {
                page = ImageUtils.getSinglePageFromTiffFile(documentToSplit, currentPageIndex);

                if(NEWPAGE) {
                    writer.endWriteSequence();
                    break;
                }

                writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(page, null, null), writeParams);
            }

        } finally {
            if(imgOutStream != null) imgOutStream.close();
            if(outStream != null) outStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My reservations on this approach apply to memory usage. While processing files, up to 2GB of memory were being allocated. On average around 1 - 1.5GB. Is there a way to perform those operations more efficient in regard to memory usage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44565928/1428606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the TIFF-pages as BufferedImages, you essentially decompress the stored images, which might need a lot of memory depending on the size of the images: Every pixel will take up 3 (RGB) or 4 (ARGB) bytes, so an image with 10000 x 10000 pixels would take up around 300 or 400 MBs.

Depending on the amount of memory assigned to your Java process, and depending on when Garbage Collection kicks in, your process might indeed actually accumulate a lot of used memory.

As the main memory consumption likely comes from the decompressed images (`BufferedImage`), the most effective way to reduce the memory used is not to decompress the single images to extract them. I don't know of any way how to do this with plain Java, but there are third party libraries which can do this. One of them is [iCafe](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe) which claims to:

> Split multipage TIFF image into individual TIFF images without decompression the images

I use this library for other image formats (e.g. creating animated GIFs), but haven't used it for TIFFs yet, but I think it's definitely worth a try. On it's [Wiki-Page](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/wiki) it provides the following snippet to split a multi-page TIFF:

```
import com.icafe4j.io.RandomAccessInputStream;
import com.icafe4j.io.FileCacheRandomAccessInputStream;
import com.icafe4j.util.FileUtils;

public class TestTIFFTweaker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        RandomAccessInputStream rin = new FileCacheRandomAccessInputStream(fin);
        TIFFTweaker.splitPages(rin, FileUtils.getNameWithoutExtension(new File(args[0])));
        rin.close();
        fin.close(); // Need to close the underlying stream explicitly!!!
    }
}
```