# Image compression and ImageIO library

Tags: java, image-processing, compression, tiff

My application is responsible for splitting a single TIFF file into multiple smaller files using particular alghoritm. Everything works fine but what the thing that concerns me is the fact that files produced by application overpass original files in size.

Total size of original files that were processed by application is about 26mb with total size of produced files equal 387mb! Below is a code snippet of process - I'm an amator when it comes to image compression and ImageIO library and hasn't been able to find anything helpful on the web hence I'd like to ask if there's something I could change to make those results closer. Ideally I'd like to use the same compression as with original.

```
final ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(resultsExtension).next();

  final ImageWriteParam writeParams = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
  writeParams.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_COPY_FROM_METADATA);

  BufferedImage page = ImageUtils.getSinglePageFromTiffFile(documentToSplit, currentPageIndex);

  while (currentPageIndex < pagesQty) {

    OutputStream outStream = null;
    ImageOutputStream imgOutStream = null;

    try {
      outStream = new FileOutputStream(newDocFile);
      imgOutStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outStream);

      writer.setOutput(imgOutStream);
      writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);

      writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(page, null, null), writeParams);
      currentPageIndex++;

        if (CONDITION) {
          writer.endWriteSequence();
          break;
        }

        writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(page, null, null), writeParams);
        currentPageIndex++;
      }

    } finally {
      if (imgOutStream != null) {
        imgOutStream.close();
      }
      if (outStream != null) {
        outStream.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

`getSinglePageFromTiffFile` method:

```
public static BufferedImage getSinglePageFromTiffFile(File file, int pageIndex)
  throws IOException {
ImageInputStream is = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
ImageReader reader;
try {
  reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(is).next();
  reader.setInput(is);
  return reader.read(pageIndex);
} finally {
  if (is != null) {
    is.close();
  }
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to split a multipage TIFF to multiple single page TIFFs, you might want to look into [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44565928/1428606), which demonstrates how to do this without decoding the images, thus keeping the original compression/file size.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code I interpret the following:

It seems to me that you are reading from your source image into an uncompressed data structure (the BufferedImage). This data structure does not seem to feature any information about data compression.

So in your writing logic, you do have set the "copy compression from input image" (ImageWriteParam.MODE_COPY_FROM_METADATA). As the read image does not feature any compression information by itself, the image data should be written out in an uncompressed format.

With a compressed input image and uncompressed output image, it is no wonder that the individual tiles are larger in size that the input file. While it might be possible, that the input image also has the redundancy between the pages compressed away (I don't know TIFF enough to say this for sure), I'd say it is more likely that you are just writing uncompressed image data out.

Comment: I've posted the method that returns `BufferedImage`. How can I transfer information about original file compression to output file? Is there a way to do so? I don't want to degrade quality of an original image.

Comment: ImagerReader::getImageMetadata(int imageIndex) returns an IIOMetadata. You might be able to use that in the ImageWriter, however I do not know how to do that.

Would it be ok in your project to just set fixed compression values or do you have to use the same ones as you had in the input file?